# Rails Find a Record Within ActiveRecord::Relation Object without querying database again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to find a specific record within an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so I can grab that record's attribute.

The below works, but the problem is that it is hitting the database again with that `find_by` statement.  It shouldn't have to.  There should be a way for rails to find that object within the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object as opposed to having to query the database again.

```
#returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object
@blogs = Blog.all

# Search for the blog within that ActiveRecord::Relation object, NOT the database
@blogs.find_by(id: 1).title #do this statement but don't hit the database again
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Once the relation has been loaded, you can use regular array  methods. `find` is actually a very interesting method here - if block is specified, it will be delegated to the relation target:

```
@blogs.find {|b| b.id == 1}
```

Comment: wow! great tip, long time developing on Rails without knowing this

Answer (score 16):

When you call `find_by`, it is going to hit the database.

The relation object is used to lazy load the db results.

Once they are loaded for the `all` call, you can then search within the resulting array.

If you want to look within the results already in memory in your ruby process, then you should look within the array using `find` or `detect` (which do the same thing). I tend to use `detect`, so it is clear it isn't hitting the database:

```
@blogs.detect { |b| b.id == 1 }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the defined association like this:

```
class User < AR
  has_many :roles do
    def find_for(params)
      find { |record| params.all? { |key, val| record[key] == val } }
    end
  end
end

User.first.roles.find_for(foo: 'bar', baz: 'word') # => return instance of Role if its #foo equal 'bar' and its #baz equal 'word'
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe this was the answer that solved my specific use case. Thanks @ka8725

Answer (score -3):

You can always use `where` clause. For instance

```
@blogs.where(id: 1).first.reload
```

To get (and reload from the database) @blog instance with ID 1. And keep in mind that this query will be fast, efficient and secure (in case you want to add `params[:id]` instead of hard-coded ID.

Comment: The use of ActiveRecord's [where](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method **will** result in a database query.

Comment: This will result in a Database Query. OP doesn't want that.